# When was the first recorded use of hospital readmissions as a summary statistic?

Tags: science, medicine, mathematics, statistics

When was the first recorded use, or the first recorded *intention* of use of hospital readmissions as a summary statistic?

A hospital readmission (also called a rehospitalization) is defined as a hospital admission that is unplanned, but related to a recent hospital discharge. For example, a person who returns to a hospital (and is readmitted) after surgery with an infection would be considered a hospital readmission.

The earliest reference I can find to the collection of a hospital readmission statistic is from [Pearl, R. (1921) Modern methods in handling hospital statistics. The Johns Hopkins Hospital Bulletin 32: 185](http://surveillance.mcgill.ca/aman/johns_hopkins_vol32_no364_pearl_article.pdf), in which he describes collecting readmissions with a punched card system (shown and described below). I'm not sure if Pearl ever implemented his system while working at Hopkins, but he at least *intended* to do so.

[image: An example punchcard for collecting hospital statistics, copied from Pearl, R. (1921) Modern methods in handling hospital statistics. The Johns Hopkins Hospital Bulletin 32: 185]

> The fourteenth is a split single column field It records the following
>   information... (c) Whether this case represents the first admission of
>   the patient to the hospital, or whether it is a readmission.

Despite this early reference, I strongly suspect that others have collected these data in previous work. I have investigated a few publications from the likely suspects, including Florence Nightingale, William Farr, and Major Greenwood, all of whom were pioneers in collecting hospital statistics, but I have yet to find anything that specifically mentions hospital readmissions.

Note that when I say "statistic" I don't mean a test statistic in particular, even a simple count would suffice. Even the term "hospital" I am very loosely defining here: if anyone found a clinic or any other place of medical care that measured something similar to hospital readmissions, I would be interested, even if the source was ancient.

Comment: My currently selected tags are an approximation; I don't have enough reputation to create new tags. `Statistics` in particular would be a nice tag to add here.